# Inherit generic class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have a class in dll which looks as follows

```
    // Summary:
   //     View component Builder base class.
    public abstract class WidgetBuilderBase<TViewComponent, TBuilder> : IHtmlString, IHideObjectMembers
        where TViewComponent : global::Kendo.Mvc.UI.WidgetBase
        where TBuilder : global::Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.WidgetBuilderBase<TViewComponent, TBuilder>
    {
    }
```

i want to inherit this class in my following class

```
public abstract class WidgetBuilderBase<TViewComponent, TBuilder>
```

I surf on net but most on the site i didn't get satisfactory answer
most of it says we can not inherit the generic class. why it is not possible to inherit the generic class.

I am trying to do following code

```
 public abstract class WidgetBuilderBase<TViewComponent, TBuilder> : Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.WidgetBuilderBase<TViewComponent, TBuilder>
    {

    }
```

But it gives me following error.

> The type 'TBuilder' cannot be used as type parameter 'TBuilder' in the
>   generic type or method
>   'Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.WidgetBuilderBase'.
>   There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from
>   'TBuilder' to
>   'Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.WidgetBuilderBase'.

same error for TViewComponent. How to solve this problem... :(

Any help on inheriting generic class?

Comment: you probably need to add the same generic constraints to the derived type...

Comment: But i want to make it dynamic at runtime

Comment: what do you want to be dynamic? When inheriting a generic class you also inherit it's constraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare a derived class like this:

```
public abstract class WidgetBuilderBase<TViewComponent, TBuilder> 
             : Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.WidgetBuilderBase<TViewComponent, TBuilder>
    where TViewComponent : global::Kendo.Mvc.UI.WidgetBase
    where TBuilder : global::Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.WidgetBuilderBase<TViewComponent, TBuilder>
{

}
```

You cannot override base class generic constraints in a derived classes.

Answer (score 1):

`WidgetBuilderBase<TViewComponent, TBuilder>` has some generic constraints for its type arguments:

```
where TViewComponent : global::Kendo.Mvc.UI.WidgetBase
where TBuilder : global::Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.WidgetBuilderBase<TViewComponent, TBuilder>
```

You can't declare descendant class, which can possibly violate these constraints. Hence, you must apply them to descendant class too:

```
 public abstract class WidgetBuilderBase<TViewComponent, TBuilder> : Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.WidgetBuilderBase<TViewComponent, TBuilder>
    where TViewComponent : global::Kendo.Mvc.UI.WidgetBase
    where TBuilder : global::Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.WidgetBuilderBase<TViewComponent, TBuilder>
    {

    }
```